# Conditional removal of an element from XML document tree

Tags: python, recursion, pattern-matching

My task is to do minor refactoring of some elements of XML tree in python 3, namely replace following structure:

```
<span class="nobr">
 <a href="http://www.google.com/">
  http://www.google.com/
  <sup>
   <img align="absmiddle" alt="" border="0" class="rendericon" height="7" src="http://jira.atlassian.com/icon.gif" width="7"/>
  </sup>
 </a>
</span>
```

With:

```
<span class="nobr">
 <a href="http://www.google.com/">
  http://www.google.com/
 </a>
</span>
```

I.e. - remove sup element if whole structure exactly corresponds to the one given in 1st example. I need to keep XML document during process, so regexp matching isn't somewhat possible.

I already have code which works for my purposes:

```
doc = self.__refactor_links(doc)
...
def __refactor_links(self, node):
    """Recursively seeks for links to refactor them"""
    for span in node.childNodes:
        replace = False
        if isinstance(span, xml.dom.minidom.Element):
            if span.tagName == "span" and span.getAttribute("class") == "nobr":
                if span.childNodes.length == 1:
                    a = span.childNodes.item(0)
                    if isinstance(a, xml.dom.minidom.Element):
                        if a.tagName == "a" and a.getAttribute("href"):
                            if a.childNodes.length == 2:
                                aurl = a.childNodes.item(0)
                                if isinstance(aurl, xml.dom.minidom.Text):
                                    sup = a.childNodes.item(1)
                                    if isinstance(sup, xml.dom.minidom.Element):
                                        if sup.tagName == "sup":
                                            if sup.childNodes.length == 1:
                                                img = sup.childNodes.item(0)
                                                if isinstance(img, xml.dom.minidom.Element):
                                                    if img.tagName == "img" and img.getAttribute("class") == "rendericon":
                                                        replace = True
            else:
                self.__refactor_links(span)
        if replace:
            a.removeChild(sup)
    return node
```

This one doesn't run through all of the tags recursively - if it matches something similar to the structure it seeks - even if it fails, it doesn't continue to look for structure inside these elements, but in my case i'm not ought to do it (although that would be nice to have too, but cost of adding bunch of else: self.__refactor_links(tag) kills it in my eyes).

If any condition fails then no removal should occur. Is there a cleaner way to define set of conditions, avoiding huge set of 'ifs'? Some custom data structure may be used to store conditions, e.g. ('sup', ('img', (...))), but i have no idea how it should be processed. If you have any suggestions or examples in python - please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Ouch.  `import this`: `... Flat is better than nested. ...`

Answer (score 1):

This is most definitely a task for an XPath expression, in your case probably in conjunction with [lxml](https://codespeak.net/lxml/xpathxslt.html#the-xpath-method).

The XPath is probably something along the lines of:

`//span[@class="nobr"]/a[@href]/sup[img/@class="rendericon"]`

Match your tree with this XPath expression and remove all matched elements.
No need for endless if constructs or recursion.

Comment: Thanks for pointing at XPath, never worked with it. I reworked whole thing to use xml.etree.ElementTree instead of xml.dom.minidom. ElementTree 1.3 supports all features of XPath i need (http://effbot.org/zone/element-xpath.htm), so i had to switch to python 3.2 (current stable version of 3.1 has 1.2.6).

Answer (score 1):

I am not good with xml but couldn't you use the find / search on nodes

```
>>> from xml.dom.minidom import parse, parseString
>>> dom = parseString(x)
>>> k = dom.getElementsByTagName('sup')
>>> for l in k:
...     p = l.parentNode
...     p.removeChild(l)
... 
<DOM Element: sup at 0x100587d40>
>>> 
>>> print dom.toxml()
<?xml version="1.0" ?><span class="nobr">
 <a href="http://www.google.com/">
  http://www.google.com/

 </a>
</span>
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick thing with `lxml`. Highly recommend `xpath`.

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> doc = etree.XML("""<span class="nobr">
...  <a href="http://www.google.com/">
...   http://www.google.com/
...   <sup>
...    <img align="absmiddle" alt="" border="0" class="rendericon" height="7" src="http://jira.atlassian.com/icon.gif" width="7"/>
...   </sup>
...  </a>
... </span>""")
>>> for a in doc.xpath('//span[@class="nobr"]/a[@href="http://www.google.com/"]'):
...     for sub in list(a):
...         a.remove(sub)
...
>>> print etree.tostring(doc,pretty_print=True)
<span class="nobr">
 <a href="http://www.google.com/">
  http://www.google.com/
  </a>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easily accomplished using `lxml` and XSLT:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> # create the stylesheet
>>> xslt = StringIO("""
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <!-- this is the standard identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- this replaces the specific node you're looking to replace -->
  <xsl:template match="span[a[@href='http://www.google.com' and 
                    sup[img[
                      @align='absmiddle' and
                      @border='0' and
                      @class='rendericon' and
                      @height='7' and
                      @src='http://jira.atlassian.com/icon.gif' and
                      @width='7']]]]">
    <span class="nobr">
      <a href="http://www.google.com/">http://www.google.com/</a>
    </span>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>""")
>>> # create a transform function from the XSLT stylesheet
>>> transform = etree.XSLT(etree.parse(xslt))
>>> # here's a sample source XML instance for testing
>>> source = StringIO("""
<test>
  <span class="nobr">
   <a href="http://www.google.com/">
    http://www.google.com/
    <sup>
     <img align="absmiddle" alt="" border="0" class="rendericon" height="7" src="http://jira.atlassian.com/icon.gif" width="7"/>
    </sup>
   </a>
  </span>
</test>""")
>>> # parse the source, transform it to an XSLT result tree, and print the result
>>> print etree.tostring(transform(etree.parse(source)))
<test>
  <span class="nobr"><a href="http://www.google.com/">http://www.google.com/</a></span>
</test>
```

**Edit:**

I should note that none of the answers - not mine, not MattH's, and certainly not the example OP posted - do what the OP asked for, which is to replace only elements whose structure *exactly* matches

```
<span class="nobr">
  <a href="http://www.google.com/">
    http://www.google.com/
  <sup>
    <img align="absmiddle" alt="" border="0" class="rendericon" height="7" src="http://jira.atlassian.com/icon.gif" width="7"/>
  </sup>
  </a>
</span>
```

For instance, all of these examples will replace the `sup` if the `img` has a `style` attribute, or if the `sup` has another child besides `img`.

It's possible to construct an XPath expression that is much more strict in how it matches.  For instance, instead of using

```
span[a]
```

which matches any `span` with at least one `a` child, you can use

```
span[count(@*)=0 and count(*)=1 and a]
```

which matches any `span` that has no attribute and *exactly one* child element where that child is an `a`.  You can go pretty crazy with this in your quest for exactitude, e.g.:

```
span[count(@*) = 1 and
     @class='nobr' and
     count(*) = 1 and 
     a[count(@*) = 1 and
       @href='http://www.google.com' and 
       count(*) = 1 and
       sup[count(@*) = 0 and
           count(*) = 1 and 
           img[count(*) = 0 and
               count(@*) = 7 and
               @align='absmiddle' and
               @alt='' and
               @border='0' and
               @class='rendericon' and
               @height='7' and
               @src='http://jira.atlassian.com/icon.gif' and
               @width='7']]]]
```

which, at every step of the matching, ensures that the element matched contains only exactly the attributes and elements specified and no more.  (And it still doesn't verify that they don't contain text, comments, or processing instructions - if you're really serious about exactitude, use `count(node())` everywhere this is using `count(*)`.)